# When adding elements to linked list and writing out all elements the first element doesen't write out

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem with my linked list when writing out the elements:
**When running main.cpp I get the following output:**

```
myList.endInsert(5);
    cout << myList << endl;     output: nothing
    myList.headInsert(3);
    cout << myList << endl;     output : 3
    myList.headInsert(2);
    cout << myList << endl;     output : 3 2
```

I **figured the prboble is probably either in headinsert or how i costructed my operator >>:
Coder for headinsert:**

```
void IntList::headInsert(int the_number)
{
    if (head == NULL) //if list is empty
    {
        head = new IntNode; //create new dynamic variable
        head -> data = the_number; //add value to new variable
        head -> link = NULL; //    }
    else
    {
        NodePtr temp = new IntNode;
        temp -> data = the_number;
        temp ->link = head; //temp pointer becomes head
        head = temp; //head becomes temp
    }

**And here is the friend function for the operator:**



 ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const IntList& lis)
    {

      for(NodePtr temp = lis.head; temp->getLink() != NULL; temp = temp->getLink())
      {

        if( temp->getLink() != NULL)
          {
              outs << " ";
              outs << temp->getData();
          }

      }
      return outs;
    }
```

Can anyone shed some light on what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any reason not using std::list?

Comment: every time you add a new element, it becomes the "head" is that the intention?

Answer (score 1):

you don't print your last item...

```
  for(NodePtr temp = lis.head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->getLink())
  {
     outs << " ";
     outs << temp->getData();
  }
```

should do it (not tested :) .

Comment: Good on you! but still if there is no reason (like this is homework) use std::list. otherwise [this link](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/linkedlist.htm) could help a bit.

Comment: Yes this is homework, Thanks for the help. I'll check the link out :)

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the first element you set

```
head->link == null;
```

when you later print the check

```
if( temp->getLink() != NULL)
{
  outs << " ";
  outs << temp->getData();
}
```

you wont print the first element since it is null.

Remove:

```
if( temp->getLink() != NULL)
```

and it should work

Answer (score -1):

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const IntList& lis)
{

  for(NodePtr temp = lis.head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->getLink())
  {

    //if( temp->getLink() != NULL)
      {
          outs << " ";
          outs << temp->getData();
      }

  }
  return outs;
}
```

That's it! Must work now!